# User authentication in a dialogflow chatbot using angular

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, dialogflow-es

i want to develop a dialogflow chatbot using angular. The chatbot will include a user authentication flow after that a messaging flow. i have skimmed through the internet and could not find a legit source for getting this thing done. i would really appreciate the community if they can help me with some insight.

Comment: please explain it properly

Comment: The landing page will prompt the user to login, after successful login the user can use the dialogflow chatbot